# how to use keys with couchbase views

Tags: view, dictionary, couchbase

i am trying to filter views results.
i am using this map:

```
function (doc,meta){
   emit(arraydate([doc.date],doc.id);
 }
```

reduce by _count

result with group level 2  is:

[2014,1]
undefined
    1819
[2014,2]
undefined
    35

now i want to filter only 2014,1

i am trying key=2014,1 , key="2014,1" , key="[2014,1]" and its always fail and i get 0 rows . i am using the ui to set the key search.
 i want to find a way to use the key for filfering and the keys range filtering
thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Your function should be

```
function(doc,meta) {
  if(meta.type == "json") {
    if(doc.date) {
      emit(dateToArray(doc.date));
    }
  }
}
```

This will produce keys like [2014,2,3,0,0,0], so to return only data for the first month of 2014 you'd use:

startKey = [2014,1] 
endKey = [2014,2]

You don't need to emit the doc id as they id is automatically emitted and is accessible from the viewRow as id.

Comment: What if i am aiming to a certein value? your answer seems to work only on range keys.

Comment: You mean a specific user?  There is no need to filter on the user if you already know what you want as you can just use the key.  Explain what you want in more detail preferably in your original question and then I can try again!